# Angular Getting MIME type error when refreshing and entering path directly, but not when navigating programatically

Tags: angular

So I'm in a bit of a pickle. I am working on a Angular app and I am having trouble with routing with regards path parameters.

In my Routes I have these (there are other paths):

```
{ path: 'reviews', component: ReviewsDisplayMainComponent },
{ path: 'reviews/:id', component: ReviewViewerMainComponent },
```

I can navigate to the second route when I do so with `router.navigate`, but when refresh or type in the path into the browser I get:

```
MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

How is it working when I navigate using router, but not when I either type in the path into the browser or refresh?

Also, I can go directly to the first route and refresh it without issue, so it is something about the `'reviews/:id'` that is causing a problem

In case relevant: they are two different modules

Comment: Is there something you're doing with the `id` only on onInit, using some services or methods that won't be triggered again after onInit?

Comment: I use the ``` id ``` to make an api call

Answer (score 0):

After asking a friend that knew quite a bit, the problem is that the index.html file didnt have a head with `<base href="/">`